# Java classes and packages

Tags: java

Hello everybody I am a beginner of Java. I am blocked at this point with the following
program:

```
import prog.io.Orario;
import prog.io.ConsoleOutputManager;
class primoprogramma{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        ConsoleOutputManager video=new ConsoleOutputManager();
        video.println("ciao");
    }
}
```

That gives me the error:

```
bad class file: ./prog/io/Orario.class
class file contains wrong class: prog.utili.Orario

Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
```

I did everything I could tried in those days but nothing works. Here there the class
Orario:

```
package prog.utili;
public class Orario {
    private static char separaratore=';';
}
```

Thank you for any advice

Comment: Please look up Java basics for packages.

Comment: I urge you to use an IDE such as eclipse(https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/), intellJ (http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/) or netbeans (https://netbeans.org/downloads/) for coding. The package thing can be a real nightmare for beginners.

Comment: See Elliotte Rusty Harold's guide [Managing the Java classpath (Windows)](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-classpath-windows/) on developerWorks for an introduction.

Comment: Besides what the other said about packages, as a comment, I suggest you to use English identifiers for variables, classes, etc... and not Italian otherwise you'll eventually find trouble asking for help (your variables don't tell anything about what they are).

Comment: I can't use eclipse because I am following a book that uses just linux terminal. Yes I think to read something about packages! Ok I will change to English next time. gd1 are you from Italy?

Answer (score 4):

Your class `Orario` has the wrong package declaration (`package prog.utili;` instead of `package prog.io;`)

1. The compiler scans your import of `prog.io.Orario`.
2. It searches for class `Orario` in a file `Orario.class` in directory `prog/io`.
3. The class found has the package `prog.utili` declared which is not the desired one - Error

Answer (score 1):

In java, directorys are the same as package names.
So, a class Orario in the package prog.utili
have to be in a directory prog/utili instead of prog/io